# particles.js and window is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, particles.js

When I start my app using `node app.js` then then I get the following error:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/nodeapp/node_modules/particles.js/particles.js:1429
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/nodeapp/node_modules/particles.js/particles.js:1429:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/nodeapp/app.js:5:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

I'm trying to use particles.js as my background, I installed the package with npm. Here what my app.js looks like:

```
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
var request = require("request")
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var particlesJS = require("particles.js")
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static("public")); 

particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json', function() {
  console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
});



app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("main")
})



app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Movie App has started!!!");
})
```

And Im storing particles.json inside assets folder. The html looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <div id="particles-js"></div>
        <script src="particles.js"></script>
        <title>MYMDB</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `particles.js` file, you will see that it is trying to access the window global variable.

The window object is a browser API call that you don't have access to it in your server-side code.

So just moving your `require("particles.js")` code to a place where you have access to the window object, will be enough. (note that I didn't assign it to `particlesJS variable` because no exporting is done in `particles.js` file. just assigning some functions to the window object is done.)

so wait for the window object to be loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
  require("particles.js");

  particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json', function() {
  console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `window` is a browser object, and it looks like you're trying to load particle.js on the server side, in node.

Try moving your `particlesJS.load` call into the browser.

From their npm page:

> Initialize the plugin on the window.onload event.

```
window.onload = function() {
  Particles.init({
    selector: '.background'
  });
};
```

Comment: Without having seen your code, it's hard to say, but that should be fine

Comment: well the app.js is my main backend file and apart from that i use ejs templates and that would be it