# ERROR ReferenceError: particlesJS is not defined ~ Angular Universal + Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, nestjs, angular-universal, particles

In my Angular component have perfectly working [particles.js](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/), it works great when rendering on the client side using `ng serve`. However, when using this in conjuction with Angular Universal for Server-Side Rendering (SSR), I'm getting the error `ERROR ReferenceError: particlesJS is not defined`. I have tried to use webpack to whitelist this, but didn't work, the code is as follows for the webpack:

```
config.externals = nodeExternals({
  // The whitelisted ones will be included in the bundle.
  whitelist: [/^ng-circle-progress/, /^ng2-tel-input/, /^particles.js/]
});
```

Errors from these other 2 packages were gone, but this one doesn't want t o disappear.

Using NestJS for my back-end, and tried to `applyDomino`, but it also didn't help, the code is as follows:

```
import { AngularUniversalModule, applyDomino } from '@nestjs/ng-universal';
import { join } from 'path';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

// Get working directory of client bundle.
const BROWSER_DIR = join(
  process.cwd(),
  'functions',
  'dist',
  'apps',
  'ditectrev-browser'
); // Use when testing locally without Firebase Cloud Functions solely on NestJS.
// const BROWSER_DIR = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/apps/ditectrev-browser'); // Use when deploying to & testing with Firebase Cloud Functions.

applyDomino(global, join(BROWSER_DIR, 'index.html'));

@Module({
  imports: [
    AngularUniversalModule.forRoot({
      bundle: require('./../functions/dist/apps/ditectrev-server/main'), // Bundle is created dynamically during build process.
      liveReload: true,
      viewsPath: BROWSER_DIR
    })
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Interesting is that even if I'm getting the error, the page renders correctly on the server side! It does **not** break. The same error occurs when rendering using solely, as well as Cloud Functions for Firebase (locally and deployment).

Note: This topic didn't help to find answer for my question [particles.js and window is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125954/particles-js-and-window-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [domino](https://www.npmjs.com/package/domino). There you can access your DOM on the server.

[Here](https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/blob/master/server.ts#L11) is an example for Angular SSR and domino.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but you can see in the code that I'm using its NestJS implementation called `applyDomino`.