# Particle.js not working when called using backend giving error of windows is not defined

Tags: html, css, node.js, particles.js

I am getting the error of windows is not defined.
I am trying to load particles.js from backend as i intend to use it to make a login system. If there is a better way to make a login system without having to go through this problem I would really like to know!

Also if anyone could help me make this more responsive that would be really helpful!

Thanks!

Here's the code for my backend system:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var particleJS = require("particles.js")
var app = express();

const mysql = require('mysql');

const mySqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "backen",
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));


particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json', function() {
    console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
  });


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/Register.html');
})
```

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="reg.css"> -->
    <style>
    body{
      margin: 0;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
  }
  .vectus{
    color:white;
    font-family:'Trade Winds';
    /* font-weight:bold; */
    display:inline-block;
    position:fixed;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin:10px;
  }
#particles-js{
      background-image:url('https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/skriver-in-cyberpunk-2077-oz.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      z-index: -1;
  }
</style>  
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Trade+Winds&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxanium&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="vectus">VECTUS '20</div>
       <div id="particles-js"> </div>   
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

HERE IS THE ERROR MESSAGE:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\Documents\Particles Webpage\node_modules\particles.js\particles.js:1429:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\Documents\Particles Webpage\backend.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)
```

Comment: it will be helpful to provide your error message.

Comment: i updated it...

Comment: Does this question and answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125954/particles-js-and-window-is-not-defined

Comment: no @nngeek it doesent i tried that